# PHP: Safe to allow users to write custom CSS to customize a webpage on my site?

Tags: php, security

I am building a web app to allow others to design their own pages. I am using PHP, MySQL.

I was wondering. Is it SAFE to allow users to customize their pages by writing their own CSS code?

So I was thinking of a TEXTAREA field that they can then enter in their CSS code.

I am using PHP filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); to filter the string before it's saved to my database.

So.... allow it or disallow?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS itself provides no insecure operations. However, Internet Explorer exists.

Comment: "However, Internet Explorer exists".  I actually laughed out loud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

IE allows you to include JavaScript files via CSS (behavior attribute) for example. However, if ONLY the user who entered the CSS code will ever see it, it's safe.
If you restrict the allowed attributes it's also safe - but note that you have to restrict values too (again, thanks to IE, which allows dynamic values using JavaScript).

Comment: +1 for a simple "No."  I wouldn't even go there.  All the opportunities for inserting malicious code...

Comment: How about using filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) to filter it? I think it filters out javascript.

Comment: Embedding javascript in CSS won't cause `javascript:` to be in the string so I doubt that'll work.

Comment: Although I notice sites like Tumblr and Google Sites allow you to customize HTML, CSS, Javascript... wonder how they protect their security.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe in the sense that users can override your CSS with their own anyway, with a browser plug-in and so on.  Just make sure that one user can't affect the CSS for another user.

Use dedicated escaping functions to sanitise the data for your database, though.  e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL.

Comment: +1 to you as well.  I was going to suggest reading this: http://www.owasp.org/index.php?title=XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.234_-_CSS_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Style_Property_Values

Answer (score 2):

It should generally be safe to allow users to enter their own CSS code for their sites.  Browsers already implement their own user agent CSS to enforce a common styling on unstyled elements.  (From the CSS2 specification: "a user agent’s default style sheet should present the elements of the document language in ways that satisfy general presentation expectations for the document language")  Also, a large part of ensuring accessibility on a site is to allow customer user agent CSS.

Just because this likely can be safely done does not mean it should be, however. Any user could easily set the background image for an element to an inappropriate image on the web, for one example. Providing the ability to do this only opens the door for malicious attacks on your site and should be generally avoided in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize the code is the best practice.

To avoid IE holes, you can use the W3C validator to check the CSS sintax before to save.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html

Hope it helps. Ciao!